# Can we ask questions about games on Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

Can we ask questions about specific games for Ubuntu on AskUbuntu, or should we ask them on Arqade instead? I would like to ask how to get a game running but I don't know which site I should put it on.

Answer (score 15):

Making software run in Ubuntu is totally on topic for the site. So installing and making a game run are fine.

Questions about playing the game should be in arqade.

Comment: Yeap. Arqade when the question has something to do with the workings of the game (Like how to level up, find the princess, do a quest or kill the dragon)

Answer (score 3):

If the question is ubuntu related, Eg playing games in ubuntu, You can post in askubuntu, for other game related questions can be ask in arqade

Answer (score 0):

I have asked only one question on this site. Its resolution was an ubuntu-specific configuration that I found in an Ubuntu bug report. It's a 3 times notable question with now 2500 views. It is of very general interest to the community. It was and is still closed as off-topic.

So apparently, here as elsewhere on stack exchange sites, one can always ask.

Nothing prevented me from asking that question.

Comment: Nothing ever prevents you from asking a question, though you will eventually get a feel for what to ask and what not to ask.